Vapor barrier in crawlspace is stapled to the top of the space and not on the bottom
I just got a house that has a vapor barrier installed to the top of crawl space on the bottom of the insulation (image attached).
I live in the wet part of the PNW and was wondering if this is actually the best way to have the vapor barrier installed? I would imagine it would be better placed on the ground instead of potentially trapping any moisture in the insulation.
Maybe not relevant but wanted to note that the crawlspace already has a sump pump
installed.
As for next steps if I do need to move it. The plan is to take down the existing barrier and reuse it on the ground. Are there any pitfalls to be aware of as I feel this approach may be somewhat naive.




TL;DR, the plastic should be on the soil and not stapled up on your joists.
I'm also in the PNW and my crawl space has the plastic on the ground and batt insulation between the floor joists--which the home inspector passed as normal when we bought the home in 2014. I have since come to learn that the 1968 approach (when this home was constructed) leaves a great deal to be desired when measured against the current best practices of encapsulation.
If you have a sump pump already installed in the crawl space, that suggests a need for a sump pump/excessive moisture in the space. You may want to have a local company come out and do an assessment--usually free for the initial consult--to see if there is a larger problem with managing water around your foundation or if the existing sump pump system is adequate for your needs.
Also, when warm, moist air and cool, dense air meet, condensation can happen. With the plastic installed up under your floor joists, that condensation will occur along the plane of the plastic and your joists, insulation, and/or subfloor may get wet. Placing the plastic on the ground moves the plane, although kraft paper on the insulation--or the subfloor/joists--can also supply the needed interface for condensation to form. You should temporarily remove any insulation between the joists when you move the plastic to inspect for signs of mold or wood rot due to prior occurrences of condensation.
There is a YouTube channel called Crawl Space Ninja, out of the Carolinas, I believe, that has many tutorials and FAQs about proper crawl space encapsulation, which has supplanted the traditional approach of having a vented crawl space. One of their overview videos is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy68gtEi_bg.
When encapsulating, if you have soil in your crawl space, the plastic (10-12mm in thickness) should be on the soil and also continue up the foundation walls and wrap the pillars supporting the floor. (The sump should be installed underneath the plastic.) The plastic seams between separate sheets should be taped so that the barrier is continuous. Some jurisdictions require a specific gap at the top of the insulation and plastic, just below the sill plate/mud plate, to inspect for termites or other insects that may be affecting the wood at the top of the foundation.
They also recommend placing rigid foam insulation (2" thick at least) on the inside of the foundation walls and running the plastic up over it. Unless you are in an area that gets cold winters, they recommend permanently removing the batt insulation from between the floor joists. They recommend using mechanical fasteners to attach the rigid foam to the walls and a butyl rubber two-sided tape to attach the top of the plastic to the foundation walls above the foam insulation. They also recommend insulating the rim joist and air sealing all gaps in the subfloor and rim joist.
Further, all the vents should be blocked except for one that will have an exhaust fan emplaced. (This is to exhaust regular soil gases--you may want to have a radon test done to see if you need a radon mitigation system as well.)
They also recommend installing a dehumidifier sufficient to keep the crawl space at around 45-55% relative humidity (which makes the formation of mold less likely by keeping the wood of the joists and subfloor dry). This also makes the crawl space part of the climate controlled area of the home--not maintained to the same temperature/humidity/air quality as the living spaces above, but no longer subject to the vagaries of the seasons either.
Since your pictures appear to show part of your HVAC system ducting running through the space, encapsulation may help that system work less hard to meet the needs of the living space after passing though an unconditioned space--even though it appears the ducting has fiberglass insulation around it--and will improve the quality of the air in the crawl space so gases and smell won't penetrate into the living areas.
All of that can be done DIY with some rental tools and after watching some YouTube videos, but a narrow (shallow) crawl space can be challenging and you may want to seek a professional opinion from a local crawl space company before diving in.

Absolutely fantastic answer, especially that video resource provided. This is super helpful and I know how I want to process. Thank you!
